# Робота OnClickLister в фрагменте, Нельзя определить какой нажать EditText

Tags: android, android-on-click

Почему это работает

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tx1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            tx2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            tx3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            tx4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.editText1:
                    index =1;
                    break;
                case R.id.editText2:
                    index =2;
                    break;
                case R.id.editText3:
                    index =3;
                    break;
                case R.id.editText4:
                    index =4;
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (index){
                case 1:
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(editable));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(editable));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(editable));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(editable));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

А это не работает

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View buttonLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_application_form, null);
        final EditText et1=(EditText)buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        final EditText et2=(EditText)buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.appLastName);
        final EditText et3=(EditText)buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.appEmail);
        final EditText et4=(EditText)buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.appPhone);
        et1.setOnClickListener(this);
        et2.setOnClickListener(this);
        et3.setOnClickListener(this);
        et4.setOnClickListener(this);
        return buttonLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.appName:
                mIndexTextEdit=1;
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mIndexTextEdit));
                break;
            case R.id.appLastName:
                mIndexTextEdit=2;
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mIndexTextEdit));
                break;
            case R.id.appEmail:
                mIndexTextEdit=3;
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mIndexTextEdit));
                break;
            case R.id.appPhone:
                mIndexTextEdit=4;
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mIndexTextEdit));
                break;
            default:
                mIndexTextEdit=0;
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mIndexTextEdit));
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        switch (mIndexTextEdit){
            case 1:
                mName = s.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, mName);
                break;
            case 2:
                mLastName = s.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, mLastName);
                break;
            case 3:
                mEmail = s.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, mEmail);
                break;
            case 4:
                mPhone = s.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, mPhone);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Нельзя определить какой нажать EditText

При нажатии на одни из EditText в поле записывает его индекс(фрагменте не роботает), после чего по данному индексу реализуется интерфейс для изменений в EditText(фрагменте не роботает)

Comment: Что не работает и как должно совершенно из вопроса не ясно

Comment: Может надо добавить еще `addTextChangedListener(this)` для каждого `edittext`

Comment: @MaksimPonomarev спасибо вам!!!Вы мне частично помогли.
но индекс по прежнему роботает не корректно записывает идекс только после второго клика, а нужно что бы с первого записывал)